# Scroll to div - multiple locations

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu list where the user can scroll to different sections.

The problem is that with the code I'm using it refers to specific `ID` so I have to copy over and over changing `IDs`:

```
$('#asistentes-menu').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#asistentes-location").offset().top - 80
    }, 800);
});
$('#evento-menu').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#event-section").offset().top - 80 
    }, 800);
});
and so on...
```

Any idea how to change this code so I can use it for all the menu locations?

Comment: Could you not wrap it in a `each` function and change `ID` to `class` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use classes for menu items, and then perhaps a data attribute to the location it points to:

```
<a class="menu-item" data-location="asistentes-location">...</a>

...

<div id="asistentes-location">...</div>
```

And the corresponding script:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this);
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + $menuItem.data('location')).offset().top - 80
    }, 800);
});
```

Alternatively, you can also find the location's ID using the menu item's ID using some string manupilation:

```
$('#' + $menuItem.attr('id').replace('menu', 'location'))
```

**UPDATE:** If your menu items are `<a>` tags, you could simply use their `href` attribute. I would recommend this as it wouldn't break your code even if javascript is disabled.

```
<a href="#myLocation" class="menu-item">...</a>
```

And the corresponding script:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $menuItem = $(this);
    $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: $($menuItem.attr('href')).offset().top - 80
    }, 800);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // Remember to add this
    var $menuItem = $(this);
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $($menuItem.attr('href')).offset().top - 80
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#location1" class="menu-item" data-location="location1">Go to 1</a>
<a href="#location2" class="menu-item" data-location="location2">Go to 2</a>
<a href="#location3" class="menu-item" data-location="location3">Go to 3</a>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="location1">This is location 1</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="location2">This is location 2</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="location3">This is location 3</p>
```

Comment: @propcode You're welcome. Do check the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31558146/2).